# Query with $in and $nin doesn't use index

Tags: mongodb

When matching an attribute against both $in and $nin, Mongo doesn't use the index correctly.

If only $in is used, then index takes advantage of that:

```
db.assets.find({
  tags: {
    $in: ['blah']
  }
}).explain()

{
  "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
  "isMultiKey" : true,
  "n" : 6,
  "nscannedObjects" : 6,
  "nscanned" : 6,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 6,
  "nscannedAllPlans" : 6,
  "scanAndOrder" : false,
  "indexOnly" : false,
  "nYields" : 0,
  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
  "millis" : 0,
  "indexBounds" : {
    "tags" : [
      [ "blah", "blah" ]
    ]
  }
}
```

However, if $nin is involved, instead of finding documents that match $in and then filtering out those that don't pass the $nin condition, it scans all documents.

```
db.assets.find({
  tags: {
    $in: ['blah'],
    $nin: ['cat']
  }
}).explain()

{
  "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags_1",
  "isMultiKey" : true,
  "n" : 75760,
  "nscannedObjects" : 79974,
  "nscanned" : 1197016,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 79974,
  "nscannedAllPlans" : 1197130,
  "scanAndOrder" : false,
  "indexOnly" : false,
  "nYields" : 9351,
  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
  "millis" : 2331,
  "indexBounds" : {
    "tags" : [
      [ {"$minElement" : 1}, "cat" ],
      [ "cat", {"$maxElement" : 1} ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to trick Mongo to do the right thing?

Comment: This is disappointing. But it's true (I check on V2.6.4). I think you may file a "bug" to MongoDB. It's fine on V2.4.8.

Comment: Yeah looks like a bug. Issue filed: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15658

Comment: So it's a known issue introduced with some other features in 2.5.4, hopefully to be fixed in 2.7/2.8 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12281