# Mongo aggregation combines $match steps, resulting in slow query

Tags: mongodb

This question is a follow up to [Query with $in and $nin doesn't use index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351714/query-with-in-and-nin-doesnt-use-index). I've tried using aggregation to declare the order of steps.

```
db.assets.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "tags": {
        "$in": ["blah"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "tags": {
        "$nin": ["test"]
      }
    }
  }
], {"explain": true})
```

You'd think Mongo would now understand that we want to filter by $in first. Well, you'd be surprised.

```
{
  "stages" : [
    {
      "$cursor" : {
        "query" : {
          "$and" : [
            {
              "tags" : {
                "$in" : [
                  "blah"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "tags" : {
                "$nin" : [
                  "test"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "planError" : "InternalError No plan available to provide stats"
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

The planner doesn't even know what to do. It turns out it actually combines both `$match`es into one query, and then runs into the same problem as [Query with $in and $nin doesn't use index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351714/query-with-in-and-nin-doesnt-use-index), eventually returning the results in about 2-3 seconds (which corresponds to the 2331ms on the linked question).

Answer (score 1):

It looks you can trick the aggregator by inserting an empty skip step:

```
db.assets.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "tags": {
        "$in": ["blah"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "tags": {
        "$nin": ["test"]
      }
    }
  }
], {"explain": true})
```

With that, the planner will use the index and the results are returned immediately.

```
{
  "stages" : [
    {
      "$cursor" : {
        "query" : {
          "tags" : {
            "$in" : [
              "blah"
            ]
          }
        },
        "plan" : {
          "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
          "isMultiKey" : false,
          "scanAndOrder" : false,
          "indexBounds" : {
            "tags" : [
              [ "blah", "blah" ]
            ]
          },
          "allPlans" : [
            {
              "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
              "isMultiKey" : false,
              "scanAndOrder" : false,
              "indexBounds" : {
                "tags" : [
                  [ "blah", "blah" ]
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$skip" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    {
      "$match" : {
        "tags" : {
          "$nin" : [
            "test"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```